# c#.net gridview with both (sometimes displayed) button click and row click events

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview

I have a grid with the following definition.  I have included two buttons here (different types), but I really only want one, but it must be able to be hidden under certain circumstances.
With the 'ButtonField' I was able to hide it in the RowDataBound event, however, on postback (row click event), all buttons where displayed.
Clicking this button triggers two RowCommand events, one being 'Select' and one being the 'AcceptStats', which would be okay if I could hide the button when not wanted.

The 'asp:Button' displays correctly all the time, but the click event seems to have gotten lost under the row click event.
In the RowCommand event, the CommandName is always 'Select', which comes from the row click event.
I have tried adding  OnClick="btnAcceptStats_Click"  to the asp:Button, but it doesn't trigger either.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvApsimFiles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="GridViewStyle" 
    PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true" DataKeyNames="PullRequestId, RunDate"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvApsimFiles_PageIndexChanging" 
    OnRowCommand="gvApsimFiles_RowCommand"
    OnRowDataBound="gvApsimFiles_RowDataBound"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvApsimFiles_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PullRequestId" HeaderText="Pull Request Id" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RunDate" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="Run Date" ItemStyle-Width="220px" DataFormatString="{0:d MMMM, yyyy hh:mm tt}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IsMerged" HeaderText="Is Merged" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PercentPassed"  HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="Percent<br />Passed" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total Files" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"  ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" ItemStyle-Font-Size="11px" Text="Accept Stats" CommandName="AcceptStats" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAcceptStats" runat="server" Text="Accept Stats"
                    CommandName="AcceptStats"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' 
                    OnClick="btnAcceptStats_Click"
                />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In the code behind:

```
    protected void btnAcceptStats_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
        int index = gvRow.RowIndex;

        int pullRequestId = int.Parse(gvApsimFiles.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text);
        //Now we can call our web api 'merge' call
        bool mergeStatus = bool.Parse(gvApsimFiles.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text);
        if (!mergeStatus)
        {
            UpdatePullRequestMergeStatus(pullRequestId, true);
        }

    }

    protected void gvApsimFiles_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gvApsimFiles.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindApsimFilesGrid();
    }

    protected void gvApsimFiles_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "AcceptStats")
        {
            var eVal = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            int index = int.Parse(eVal.ToString());
            int pullRequestId = int.Parse(gvApsimFiles.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text);
            //Now we can call our web api 'merge' call
            bool mergeStatus = bool.Parse(gvApsimFiles.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text);
            if (!mergeStatus)
            {
                UpdatePullRequestMergeStatus(pullRequestId, true);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void gvApsimFiles_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Show as green if 100% 
            if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text.Equals("100"))
            {
                e.Row.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            //Activate the row click event
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gvApsimFiles, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";


        }
    }
```

Is there a way that I can have a button, that is only displayed when required, doesn't re-appear on postback, and triggers correctly, while maintaining the row click event?

Comment: please be specific

Comment: Hi Asif.Ali, I am not sure what you mean with 'please be specific;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.  It is through the use of Gridview_RowDataBound, updating each cell in the grid, and then on the Gridview_RowCommand, retrieving these values, and going from there.

It is slightly slower to load, but works.  The working code on the .aspx page is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvApsimFiles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="GridViewStyle" 
    PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true" DataKeyNames="PullRequestId, RunDate"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvApsimFiles_PageIndexChanging" 
    OnRowCommand="gvApsimFiles_RowCommand"
    OnRowDataBound="gvApsimFiles_RowDataBound" >
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="GridViewRowStyle" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PullRequestId" HeaderText="Pull Request Id" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RunDate" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="Run Date" ItemStyle-Width="220px" DataFormatString="{0:d MMMM, yyyy hh:mm tt}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IsMerged" HeaderText="Is Merged" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PercentPassed"  HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="Percent<br />Passed" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total Files" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"  ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAcceptStats" runat="server" Text="Accept Stats"
                    Visible='<%# Eval("IsMerged").ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Equals("false") %>'
                />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

with the code behind being:

```
   protected void gvApsimFiles_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        // Don't interfere with other commands.
        // We may not have any now, but this is another safe-code strategy.
        if (e.CommandName == "CellSelect")
        {
            // Unpack the arguments.
            String[] arguments = ((String)e.CommandArgument).Split(new char[] { ',' });

            // More safe coding: Don't assume there are at least 2 arguments.
            // (And ignore when there are more.)
            if (arguments.Length >= 2)
            {
                // And even more safe coding: Don't assume the arguments are proper int values.
                int rowIndex = -1, cellIndex = -1;
                bool canUpdate = false;
                int.TryParse(arguments[0], out rowIndex);
                int.TryParse(arguments[1], out cellIndex);
                bool.TryParse(arguments[2], out canUpdate);

                // Use the rowIndex to select the Row, like Select would do.
                if (rowIndex > -1 && rowIndex < gvApsimFiles.Rows.Count)
                {
                    gvApsimFiles.SelectedIndex = rowIndex;
                }

                //here we either update the Update Panel (if the user clicks only anything OTHER THAN our'Button'
                //or we process the UpdatePullRequest as Merged
                if (cellIndex == 5 && canUpdate == true)
                {
                    int pullRequestId = int.Parse(gvApsimFiles.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text);
                    UpdatePullRequestMergeStatus(pullRequestId, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    int pullRequestId = int.Parse(gvApsimFiles.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text);
                    BindSimFilesGrid(pullRequestId);

                }
            }
        }

    }

    protected void gvApsimFiles_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Show as green if 100% 
            if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text.Equals("100"))
            {
                e.Row.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";

            //Active cell click events on individual cells, instead of the row
            foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                // Although we already know this should be the case, make safe code. Makes copying for reuse a lot easier.
                if (cell is DataControlFieldCell)
                {
                    int cellIndex = e.Row.Cells.GetCellIndex(cell);
                    bool canUpdate = false;
                    // if we are binding the 'Button' column, and the "IsMerged' is false, then whe can Update the Merge Status.
                    if (cellIndex == 5 && e.Row.Cells[2].Text.ToLower().Equals("false"))
                    {
                        canUpdate = true;
                    }
                    // Put the link on the cell.
                    cell.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gvApsimFiles, String.Format("CellSelect${0},{1},{2}", e.Row.RowIndex, cellIndex, canUpdate));

                    // Register for event validation: This will keep ASP from giving nasty errors from getting events from controls that shouldn't be sending any.
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(gvApsimFiles.UniqueID, String.Format("CellSelect${0},{1},{2}", e.Row.RowIndex, cellIndex, canUpdate));
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide buttons, why not base their visibility on a value of the GridView inline.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("myBool")) %>' Text="Button 1" />

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Visible='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("myBool")) %>' Text="Button 2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.  I have the asp:Button displaying correctly with the following code:

```
visible='<%# Eval("IsMerged").ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Equals("false") %>'
```

The problem is that, when I use this button, I cannot get the Button Click event to work, only the row click event.  When I step through the RowCommand the CommandName is only ever 'Select'.  I am not able to trigger the 'AcceptStats' event.